# Problem with accents in dynamic <select>

Tags: php, mysql, html, character-encoding

I have a form with a , and I fill it with the result of a request in a database. My database, table and row format are UTF-8, and the browser too... But the accents appears like interrogation points... I don't understand why, could someone help me please ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem at some point too, even though I had everything on the table set to UTF-8. Using [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) fixed it for me and may work for you too.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to put it in my bdd class, and directly in the code before the <select>, but it doesn't work :(